# C# getting information in the behind form

Tags: c#, forms

I have two forms 
the first one is `FrmReceiveItems` from which I can display the second one
`FrmItemSearch`. In the second one I can choose a certain item to add to a `DataGridView` in the first form. The problem is that whenever I add an item I will have a new object from the first form. I want all chosen items to be added to the first opened form. I try to test if any object of the first form is opened .. as following:

```
private void dgv_ItemsSearch_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Connection obj = new Connection();
        //Connection.FrmChose = 10;
        FrmRecieveItemsVoucher FRI = new FrmRecieveItemsVoucher();

        Form frmT = Application.OpenForms["FRI"];
        int value = Connection.FrmChose;
        if (value == 10)
        { 
            FRI.dataGridView_ItemsVoucher.Rows.Add();
            int CurrentRowIndex = FRI.dataGridView_ItemsVoucher.Rows.Count;
            FRI.dataGridView_ItemsVoucher.Rows[CurrentRowIndex - 1].Cells[0].Value = dgv_ItemsSearch.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value;
            FRI.dataGridView_ItemsVoucher.Rows[CurrentRowIndex - 1].Cells[1].Value = dgv_ItemsSearch.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
            // here I try to test 
            if (frmT != null)
            {
                this.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                FRI.Show();
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            FrmItems frmItems = new FrmItems();
            //frmCust.btn_new(sender,e);
            string Code = Convert.ToString(dgv_ItemsSearch.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
            this.Dispose();
            frmItems.Show();
            frmItems.Show_Record_data(Code);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
    } 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us minimal, complete and verifiable example illustrating your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

well there are a lot of ways to achieve this. What I would personally go for is creating a `BindingList` and setting a `ListChanged` event on that list that would then trigger a reload in the second form.

Comment: Ok , the following code works with me

 var FrmRecieveItems = Application.OpenForms["FrmRecieveItemsVoucher"] as FrmRecieveItemsVoucher;